# XDebug not profiling POST

Tags: php, apache, xdebug-profiler

How can I configure XDebug to profile **ALL** requests, POST, GET, Ajax, with and without query string parameters?

The current configuration (below) is only creating profile (cachegrind.out) files for GET requests and POST requests that don't have query string parameters.

**/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
```

**conf.d/my.conf**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/sub">
        # Limit profiling to files in this directory
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule (.*\.php) $1?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1 [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

> Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
>
> PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
>
> XDebug version 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was that the profile file for the POST request was being overwritten by the next request which was a client side redirect.  The solution was to use a different profiler output filename

Ref: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1445

> xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s

Many thanks to the XDebug team.